# Drop Down Each Row on Tableau Table

Tags: tableau-api

I currently have a tableau table that is almost at full functionality. The data is all there, I just need to display it in a certain way. I am currently using a hierarchy to order the product, purchaser and date purchased. The hierarchy works, but I would like to know if there is a way to only show a selected column's data. So if the user selected the name purchaser, it would show all the dates they ordered the product. Is this even possible? If so how? A point in the right direction is all I need as I have meet a dead end with my knowledge and google searches come up with no leads.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not pivot table answer I was looking for, adding a action filter to go to a new worksheet displaying the data in the preferred format works fine. It adds some loading time. Alternative options would be a drill down or a drill down with an action filter, what ever is best for you.

If you are working with action filters for the first time make sure to create one for the dashboard not just the worksheet. If you make one for the worksheet, it will work there but when adding the sheets to a dash, it will not. Just something to keep in mind. Best of luck.